# Next and Prev button will slides 2 items on OWL Carousel

Tags: javascript, carousel, owl-carousel

I am using OWL Carousel (1.3.3) as bellow

```js
$(".CardSlider").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true,
  navigationText: ["ﺑﻌﺪﻯ", "ﻗﺒﻠﻰ "],
  pagination: false,
  slideSpeed: 300,
  paginationSpeed: 400,
  singleItem: true,
});
```

Everything is fine on Desktop browser, but on Mobile device when I touch `Next` or `Prev` button it slides 2 items,

First I was suspicious about the resubscription of event handlers so I added this option `mouseDrag : false` but nothing is changed.

Then I opened the owl script file and set some alerts in `next` method. when alerts are shown the functionality is OK I mean it slides 1 item.
also I check this variables in that method
            `base.currentItem += base.options.scrollPerPage === true ? base.options.items : 1;`

`base.options.scrollPerPage` = false

`base.options.items` = 1

`(base.options.scrollPerPage === true ? base.options.items : 1)` = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After not getting help from anyone even the official email address from their site I resolved my problem, On mobile device the event handler for `next` and `prev` button was assigned twice one for `click` and one for `touch`. So I have resolved the issue as this:
In `owl.carousel.js` Line 424 I have replaced this code

```js
buttonsWrapper.on("touchstart.owlControls mousedown.owlControls", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

buttonsWrapper.on("touchend.owlControls mouseup.owlControls", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($(this).hasClass("owl-next")) {
    base.next();
  } else {
    base.prev();
  }
});
```

with this

```js
if (isMobile()) {
  buttonsWrapper.on("touchstart.owlControls", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  buttonsWrapper.on("touchend.owlControls ", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("owl-next")) {
      base.next();
    } else {
      base.prev();
    }
  });
}
else {
  buttonsWrapper.on("touchstart.owlControls mousedown.owlControls", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  buttonsWrapper.on("touchend.owlControls mouseup.owlControls", "div[class^=\"owl\"]", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).hasClass("owl-next")) {
      base.next();
    } else {
      base.prev();
    }
  });
}
```

Also I have added this function at the end of js file

```
function isMobile() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPod|iPad|BlackBerry/i) !== null;
}
```